# Israel visa stamp issue

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, israel, passport-stamps

I am an Indian national living in London. I need to travel to Israel for work. I will need to apply for a visa but I have been told that it will be stamped in my passport. I have read that Israel knows of the problems travellers face in other Arab countries so they issue a paper visa but the embassy in London told me that it will be stamped in. I travel often in Middle East for work and I do not want any issues in the future. Please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: I wonder if you are confusing practice for visa-free entries with practice for visas.

Answer (score 3):

You can't get visa on arrival at Ben Gurion airport. See [a Timatic search at the Emirates site](https://www.emirates.com/hk/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=IN&NV=India&DC=IL&DV=Israel&h=46436573b6606a753f35541d08464a3c7c732fe):

```
Visa 
Visa required.

Visa Issuance: 
Passengers with a confirmation issued by the Israeli Ministry of Interior can obtain a visa on arrival if they travel in a group of 10 or more.

Warning: 
Visitors not holding return/onward tickets could be refused entry.
```

Unfortunately, it seems like Israeli visas are stamped on your passport, so it will prevent you from entering some (not all) Arab and Muslim countries, notably Iran.

You could try to get two passports, I don't know if India allows it. You can "lose" the passport with the Israeli visa.

I won't be surprised if there's a better solution, similar to stamping on a separate paper on entry. I didn't find one.

Answer (score 1):

If you travel a lot in such zones, especially on countries which will not allow any Israeli sign on passports (there are not so many now), you should ask about it for your passport issuer.

They can produce two passports. Note: you will have just one with you, but you can exchange it (at issuer place/consulate), according your travel program. You should have strong reasons (and a concrete need (and travel plan) to have a re-issue of your passport when you request it).  Just "potential" is not enough.  The hassle for them to take care about two passports should be minor than the hassle to re-issue them regularly.  And it has some costs also on you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but was able to get a paper visa at the border (I was entering from Jordan). I would check if Israel grants visas upon entry to Indian nationals and also if your intended entry point issues paper visas.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the stamp in your passport - I know that this is an old question, but just for future information - for a few years now, Israel do not stamp ANYONE arriving at the airport even if you want to. ( except very special cases ). They just issue a printed slip like some otheer countries that abolished the stamps ( Hong kong, Macau etc.. ).

I am not sure how it is in other border crossing in Israel - But i think it is the same.

If you are talking about real visa - there used to be a procedure of having a separated document issued ( something like a visa but not inside the passport ) but I am not sure it applies anymore ( and even when it was - not for all countries ) you better ask specifically at the embassy.

Comment: He's along specifically about a visa, not a passport stamp.

Comment: @ugoren I believe I have included both in the answer.

Comment: You correctly answered the question the OP didn't ask, and answered 'maybe' to the question asked.

Comment: @ugoren the real ( and only real valid ) answer is that the OP should consult the embassy / consulate for specifics for the OP own case. like I wrote.